# find corresponding values of two columns, in a database(df)

Tags: pandas

I have a very large database like this:-

```
col1    col2    col3
A1  F0000033213042  3605167
A2  F0000033213041  5705022
A3  F0000033213040  1903999
A4  F0000033213039  2090400
A5  F0000033213038  3321303
A6  F0000033213034  2546874
A7  F0000033213031  3034242
A8  F0000033213035  4806008
A9  F0000033213037  6008700
A10 F0000033213033  6008701
A11 F0000033213032  6008702
A12 F0000033213033  4806009
A13 F0000048060086  4808698
A14 F0000048060087  4808690
```

and I have a file that has two columns, some data are missing and need to find from the database:

```
Sample          Id_Sample
                1903999
                2090400
                3321303
F0000033213034  
                3034242
F0000033213033  
F0000048060086  
                4806008
```

I would like to find corresponding values for "sample" from col2 in the database and corresponding value of "Id_Sample" in col3 of database.
finally I would like to have below table:

```
Sample          Id_Sample
F0000033213040  1903999
F0000033213039  2090400
F0000033213038  3321303
F0000033213034  2546874
F0000033213031  3034242
F0000033213033  4806009
F0000048060086  4808698
F0000033213035  4806008
```

I used Pandas to create two datafram fraom database and the table,

Any suggestions is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the most efficient way of doing this, but assuming that the missing values are represented as NaNs, you could use the [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) function to iterate over the records and replace the missing values using the database as a lookup table:

```
# setup
import pandas as pd

complete_data_columns = ["col1", "col2", "col3"]
incomplete_data_columns = ["Sample", "Id_Sample"]

complete_data = [
    ["A1", "F0000033213042",  3605167],
    ["A2", "F0000033213041",  5705022],
    ["A3", "F0000033213040",  1903999],
    ["A4", "F0000033213039",  2090400],
    ["A5", "F0000033213038",  3321303],
    ["A6", "F0000033213034",  2546874],
    ["A7", "F0000033213031",  3034242],
    ["A8", "F0000033213035",  4806008],
    ["A9", "F0000033213037",  6008700],
    ["A10", "F0000033213033",  6008701],
    ["A11", "F0000033213032",  6008702],
    ["A12", "F0000033213033",  4806009],
    ["A13", "F0000048060086",  4808698],
    ["A14", "F0000048060087",  4808690]
]

incomplete_data = [
    [np.nan,                   1903999],
    [np.nan,                   2090400],
    [np.nan,                   3321303],
    ["F0000033213034",          np.nan],
    [np.nan,                   3034242],
    ["F0000033213033",          np.nan],
    ["F0000048060086",          np.nan],
    [np.nan,                   4806008]
]

# Building complete and incomplete dataframes
complete_data = pd.DataFrame(complete_data, columns = complete_data_columns)
incomplete_data = pd.DataFrame(incomplete_data, columns = incomplete_data_columns)

# function to apply to records
# 
def fillmissing(x):
    if pd.isnull(x[incomplete_data_columns[1]]):
        return x[incomplete_data_columns[0]], int(complete_data[complete_data[complete_data_columns[1]] == x[incomplete_data_columns[0]]][complete_data_columns[2]].values[-1])
    elif pd.isnull(x[incomplete_data_columns[0]]):
        return complete_data[complete_data[complete_data_columns[2]] == x[incomplete_data_columns[1]]][complete_data_columns[1]].values[-1], int(x[incomplete_data_columns[1]])
    else:
        return x0l

# applying function on columns
inc_to_comp = incomplete_data.apply(fillmissing, axis=1, result_type="expand")

# setting the name of the columns
inc_to_comp.columns = incomplete_data.columns

# result
print(inc_to_comp)
```

Output:

```
           Sample  Id_Sample
0  F0000033213040    1903999
1  F0000033213039    2090400
2  F0000033213038    3321303
3  F0000033213034    2546874
4  F0000033213031    3034242
5  F0000033213033    4806009
6  F0000048060086    4808698
7  F0000033213035    4806008
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can try:

```
df2['Sample'] = df2['Sample'].fillna(df2['Id_Sample'].astype(
    'Int32').map(dict(df1[['col3', 'col2']].values)))
df2['Id_Sample'] = df2['Id_Sample'].fillna(
    df2['Sample'].map(dict(df1[['col2', 'col3']].values)))
```